# How to add column as foreign key with cascade delete in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have two table
one product and another usage

```
Product
#  id                  :integer          not null, primary key
#  product_name        :string           not null
#  plan_id             :string
#  plan_name           :string

Usage
#  id              :integer          not null, primary key
#  quantity        :float
#  date            :date
```

Want to add product_id as foreign key in usage

i am trying to run migration

```
 def change
    add_reference(:usages, :products, foreign_key: { on_delete: :cascade })
 end
```

Getting error column "product_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

Comment: I think  `add_reference(:usages, :product, foreign_key: { on_delete: :cascade })`. It should be singular. `product` instead of `products`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is ref_name should be singular

```
 add_reference(:usages, :product, foreign_key: { on_delete: :cascade })
```